# SUBSTRING operation does not work in JOIN operation

Tags: apache-pig

I have a column col1 in file 1:

```
00SPY58KHT5
00SPXB2BD0J
00SPXB2DXH6
00SPXDQ02S1
00SPXDY91JI
00SPXFG88L6
00SPXF1AQ4Z
00SPXF5UKS3
00SPXGL9IV6
```

I have column col2 in file2:

```
0SPY58KHT5
0SPXB2BD0J
0SPXB2DXH6
0SPXDQ02S1
0SPXDY91JI
0SPXFG88L6
0SPXF1AQ4Z
0SPXF5UKS3
0SPXGL9IV6
```

As you can see there is different of 0 in the first one in the beginning

I need to do JOIN operation between two files by these columns. So I need to use substring like this :

```
 JOIN_FILE1_FILE2 = JOIN FILE1  BY TRIM(SUBSTRING(col1,1,10)), FILE1  BY TRIM(col2); 

DUMP JOIN_FILE1_FILE2;
```

But I get empty result.

```
Input(s):
Successfully read 914493 records from: "/hdfs/data/adhoc/PR/02/RDO0/GUIDES/GUIDE_CONTRAT_USINE.csv"
Successfully read 102851809 records from: "/hdfs/data/adhoc/PR/02/RDO0/BB0/MGM7X007-2019-09-11.csv"

Output(s):
Successfully stored 0 records in: "hdfs://ha-manny/hdfs/hadoop/pig/tmp/temp964914764/tmp1220183619"
```

How can I did this jointure please ?

Answer (score 0):

As a solution I generate first data to applicate the SUBSTRING function to the col1.
Then I did the filtration using TRIM and finally use CONCAT('0',col1) in other generation.

In other words

```
DATA1 = FOREACH DATA_SOURCE GENERATE
        SUBSTRING(col1,1,10) AS col1;

JOINED_DATA = JOIN DATA1 BY col1, ...

FINAL_DATA = FOREACH JOINED_DATA GENERATE
           CONCAT('0',col1) AS col1,
...
```

And this works without problem.